# C# get property returns wrong integer

Tags: c#

Here's the program.

```
using System;

public class Program {

    public static int Main(string[] args) {

        Stock obj = new Stock();
        obj.Number = 30;
        obj.Number -= 3;
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Number);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

after executing the program with this code below,

```
public class Stock {
    int number;

    public int Number {
        get { return ++number; }
        set { number = value; }
    }
}
```

Screen displays 29. I'm expecting it to be 28.

and with this code below,

```
public class Stock {
    int number;

    public int Number {
        get { return number * 3; }
        set { number = value; }
    }
}
```

Gives 261 instead of 81.

Why?

Comment: `public static int Main(string[] args)`? really? Who is getting this `int` value?

Comment: Learn to debug. Put a breakpoint at the beginning of your program and step through line by line. Or if you wanted to be more precise put a breakpoint in your getter and see when it is getting hit. You would immediately get the answer to why it is doing what it is doing.

Comment: @ZoharPeled It's set as environment variable

Comment: Note that property getter with side effect (like `++number` in your case) is never a good idea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's called one more time than you are expecting because this line:

```
 obj.Number -= 3;
```

is equivalent to `obj.Number =  obj.Number - 3;`

Which is basically calling your getter and setter.

Answer (score 2):

Before subtracting `3`, `Number` is incremented by 1 because of prefix `++`.

**UPDATE**

When you use prefix `++`:

1. `number` is incremented by 1
2. `number` returns to the caller

When you use postfix `++`:

1. `number` returns to the caller
2. `number` is incremented by 1

Let's add backing field number and make it public for illustration purposes only:

```
public class Stock
{
    public int number; //public - only for illustration

    public int Number
    {
        get { return number; }
        set { number = value; }
    }
}
```

**With prefix** (`return ++number`):

```
var stock = new Stock();
stock.number = 10; //Set backing field directly 
Console.WriteLine($"Number backing field now is: {stock.number}"); // 10
Console.WriteLine($"Get Number with prefix: {stock.Number}");      // 11
Console.WriteLine($"Number backing field now is: {stock.number}"); // 11
```

**With postfix** (`return number++`):

```
var stock = new Stock();
stock.number = 10; //Set backing field directly 
Console.WriteLine($"Number backing field now is: {stock.number}"); // 10
Console.WriteLine($"Get Number with postfix: {stock.Number}");     // 10
Console.WriteLine($"Number backing field now is: {stock.number}"); // 11
```

As you see, with postfix the `Number` property returns non-incremented `number` backing field, while with prefix - `number` is updated before returning to the caller.

Comment: Ah, on rereading perhaps you have, just not very clearly. I think your answer could really do with being clear that the increment is being run twice in the program. I will still stand by my comment that your answer adds nothing that wasn't in the existing answer though (and while often I appreciate that other answers appear while you are writing yours I feel confident that this answer didn't take five minutes to write. ;-)

Comment: I would probably delete it personally. Or if you improved your answer I'd probably give it an upvote (I believe in rewarding people for time put in).